# get JSON data from URL react- problems with formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsonschema

I saw that helpful code in an issue:

```
getSchemaFromApiAsync() {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        return responseJson;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

I have this problem: I want to get my responseJson as a js object or covert it to a js object. I tried JSON.stringify but does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: can you paste your response too ?

Comment: and console.log(responseJson) please.

Comment: @oma Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
catch: ƒ catch()
constructor: ƒ Promise()
finally: ƒ finally()
then: ƒ then()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"
__proto__: Object
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined

Comment: @ZeroCho see the answer up. a promise function.

Answer (score 0):

your return value is the promise function

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.getObject();
}

getObject(){
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
          this.setState({responseJson : responseJson});
         return responseJson;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}
```

Now your state has set.You can access this state variable where ever you want(another component also).

Comment: how? ur componentWillMount() returns again a promise fun

Comment: For example, this.setState({ rs }) after console.log(rs);

Comment: I just written a componentWillMount() for understanding purpose, you can use what ever(function) you want.

Comment: @ZeroCho it returns again a promise fun. please do not answer if u are not sure about it.

Comment: tell me how you are calling you method ?

Comment: you can set a state variable in `getSchemaFromApiAsync()` itself. like `then(responsejson => { this.setState({rs : responsejson })})`

Comment: @SubrahmanyamJanapamula console.log(rs); inside the componentWillMount() returns the correct value. Then I also write return rs inside the method. Then, I did this and returns undefined const schema1 = this.componentWillMount(); console.log(schema1);

Comment: @SubrahmanyamJanapamula then(responsejson => { this.setState({rs : responsejson })}) and the initial value of rs? I need to declare it inside the constructor(props) method.

Comment: you can access the state variables by using the props.

Comment: @SubrahmanyamJanapamula can u give me an example because  this.setState({ rs }); does not work also

Comment: okay tell me how you want to use this data ? in same component or another ?

Comment: @SubrahmanyamJanapamula same component. I want to save it a const variable so that I  can pass it to another component as props. My only problem is that I want to get what your initial componentWillMount() gives in the console and save it to a const variable.

Comment: @SubrahmanyamJanapamula  it does not work again. If I do 
 console.log(componentWillMount()); , it returns undefined. If I do console.log(getSchemaFromApiAsync()); , it returns a promise fun and each time the state of the component is changing. A better solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183107/discussion-between-subrahmanyam-janapamula-and-kathrine-hanson).

Answer (score 0):

Try this using ES6 syntax, hope you have the latest libraries to support this.

```
let getSchemaFromApiAsync = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {
     fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then(response => resolve(response.json()))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        reject(error);
      });
    })
  }

  let main = async () => {
    let res = await getSchemaFromApiAsync();
    console.log("res", res);
  };

  main();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it do not support this library. Again console.log("res", res); returns a promise func and console.log(main()); returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it in your related rest api. Use json.stringyfy in your nodejs file.
Set your json response to scope.